# Inverting an equation in the derivation of the comoving distance

Tags: cosmology

It's given that
$$z \approx H_0(t_0-t_e)+(1+q_0/2)H_0^2(t_0-t_e)^2~~(1)$$
and later they invert this equation and write
$$t_0-t_e \approx H_0^{-1}[z-(1+q_0/2)z^2]~~(2)$$

I have tried to derive this relation but no luck. I have write the Eq.1 as,
$z = ax+ca^2x^2$ where $a\equiv H_0$ and $c\equiv (!+q_0/2)$. Then I used wolframalpha, which gives me

$$t_0-t_e = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1 + 4cz}}{2ac}$$

But this does not look like Eq.2

any ideas how can I obtain Eq.2 from Eq.1 ?

Comment: Hint: Write $H_0 (t_0 - t_e) = \alpha z + \beta z^2$. Plug this guess into your first equation for $z$ (Eq 1). For consistency, you need $z=z$. So, set the coefficient of the $z$ term to $1$ and solve for $\alpha$, then set the coefficient of the $z^2$ term to $0$ and solve for $\beta$.

Comment: Okay, it works, thanks a lot. But why my approach is not working

Comment: I think what you did should work in principle, but you need to make a couple of corrections. (a) There should be a factor of $-z$ in the denominator. (b) You should expand your solution for $t_0-t_e$ to second order in $z$.

Comment: I see....in that case your approach is still better. I am still trying to expand the $a(t)$ up to third order so in that case your approach is much better. I hope I can find the correct solution...otherwise I ll go with up to second order...

Comment: Yeah, in perturbation theory you should only ever be solving a linear equation. Solving an equation using the quadratic or even the cubic formula is overly complicated and also kind of misleading, in the sense that you are writing down an exact solution to an equation that is only approximately correct. Writing the square root (instead of expanding it to second order) implies that you know the solution more precisely than you really do.

Comment: I see...that makes sense